# How can I do a GBA Link with mrenxo's GBA emulator?

Tags: emulation, game-boy-advance

I am using this website (https://mrenxo.github.io/gba) to play GBA games, and I was wondering if it can do linking. Does anyone know if it's possible?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe this emulator supports link play. I did a little research and found out a few things. It's a JavaScript-based emulator, and the github pages linked in question (that hosts the emulator) is forked from [walsh's 'gba' repository](https://github.com/walsh/gba), where the README states that the core of the emulator (the part that provides functionality) is from [taisel's IodineGBA](https://github.com/taisel/IodineGBA).

While it isn't explicitly stated in between these three sources, MrEnXo's pages, walsh's pages, or taisel's core, that link play is either supported or not, I haven't seen any code from taisel's core that would suggest it's possible, and it doesn't seem that walsh/MrEnXo added it either. Please note that there are other emulators (written in different languages, more robust, usually not served as a webapp) that include link play, but this doesn't seem to be one of them.

Comment: while not entirely relevant to the question, I believe it's important to note (and give credit) to taisel, as he seems to be the original developer/host of this emulator.